# Always show problems inline in VSCode

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

VSCode lists all problems in the Problem panel but I would rather show them inline without hitting F8 all the time (see screenshot below).

Is that somehow possible or will I need to build an extension for this myself?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This Visual Studio extension shows errors inline: Error Lens

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=usernamehw.errorlens

Comment: Using this myself. Works great

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.

There is no setting for this behavior and the extension api does not make a general solution possible for an extension.